# ReSharper navigation to .NET Core sources shows stubs only: how to move further to impl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When you navigate in **.Net Framework** project (with **JetBrains decompiler** on Ctrl+Click) ReSharper can **decompile GAC assemblies on-the-fly and shows implementation**.

The same behavior **on .Net Core shows stubs only** from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Runtime.dll`.

[image: Stubs]

ReSharper 2017.2.1

Comment: You might be interested to know that this bug is marked as fixed in version 2017.3 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466583). That version is not available yet (though Early Access Program version is), but should be available soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've [asked](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000639990-Navigate-to-source-and-NET-Core) that on Resharper support forum (because this problem also bothers me every day) and they confirmed (as far as I understand at least) that this is a bug and created an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466583). So as far as I can tell from that - you cannot fix that yourself and have to just wait until they fix it (issue has "Major" priority so there is chance it will happen in not that far future).

Update: this bug has been marked as fixed in version 2017.3.

Comment: Looks like the right answer. The ticket stats: Fix version
2017.3. But that's maybe not a fixed commitment.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't imagine that it's a simple bug:)

Comment: It was marked as fixed but it still remains active?  FWIW when I decompile .NET Core assemblies I get reference assembly code and not runtime.  Do you have any workarounds that you have been using to get this to work, by chance?

Comment: This is really bad. The bug still exists, as of February 2019. Is there any external tool that does this properly, so I can decompile the assemblies I need and just point R# to that folder?